# Continuous embedding of weighted Lebesgue space

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, harmonic-analysis

Let $w$ belong to the class of Muckenhoupt weight $A_p$ for some $1<p<\infty$ and define the weighted Lebsgue space 
$$
L^p(\Omega,w):=\left\{u:\Omega\to\mathbb{R} \text{ measurable }: ||u||=\left(\int_{\Omega}|u|^pw(x)\,dx\right)^\frac{1}{p}<\infty\right\}.
$$
One can prove that for any cube $Q$ in $\mathbb{R}^N$ ($N\geq 2$), there exist $s=s(A_p(w))>1$ such that for $q=\frac{ps}{p+s-1}$, we have
$$
\left(\frac{1}{|Q|}\int_{Q}|f|^q\,dx\right)^\frac{1}{q}\leq C(A_p(w))\left(\frac{1}{w(Q)}\int_{Q}|f|^p w\,dx\right)^\frac{1}{p},
$$
for every $f\in L^p(Q,w)$ and for some constant $C=C(A_p(w))$ depending on the $A_p$ constant $A_p(w)$ of $w$.

My question is that does the above inequality imply that for any bounded smooth domain $\Omega$ in $\mathbb{R}^N$, one has 
$$
\left(\int_{\Omega}|f|^q\,dx)^\frac{1}{q}\leq C(\int_{\Omega}|f|^p w\,dx\right)^\frac{1}{p}
$$
for every $f\in L^p(Q,w)$ with some constant $C$ independent of $f$.

Can you please help me regarding this.

This is mentioned in the paper (page 7) in the link : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.05061.pdf

Comment: Just encase your domain $\Omega$ in a big cube, extend $f$ by zero and apply the inequality above, the one on cubes.

Comment: By entending $f$ by zero in $Q\setminus\Omega$, I have got the following inequality,

Comment: $(\int_{\Omega}|f|^q w\,dx)^\frac{1}{q}\leq C(A_p(w))\frac{|Q|^\frac{1}{q}}{w(Q)^\frac{1}{p}}(\int_{\Omega}|f|^p w\,dx)^\frac{1}{p}$, where $w(Q)=\int_{Q}w\,dx$.

Comment: Now, the right side constant is fixed for any fixed $w$ and positive, so I have the requried embedding. Is the argument correct? Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, it is. Best write it as an answer.

Comment: Can you kindly have a look at the following question in the link:\https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3054847/example-of-a-function-in-the-weighted-morrey-space

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3054847/example-of-a-function-in-the-weighted-morrey-space